# ProgressbarStyle issues

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, styles

I have a ProgressbarStyle in which I add a TextBlock-Control to the Grid "DeterminateRoot". This TextBlock should display a Status-Text, which I change manually in CodeBehind and this works already.

Here is the part of my style, which I change in the standard ProgressbarStyle:

> ```
>    <Grid x:Name="DeterminateRoot" Margin="1">
>         <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RadiusY="1.5" RadiusX="1.5" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
>         <TextBlock x:Name="txtbStatusText" Text="5 of 20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11"></TextBlock>
>    </Grid>
> ```

My question is: How can I change the Foregroundcolor of the TextBlock-Text to black, without changing the standardcolor of the progressbar? Because, when I delete the Fill-Property of the Rectangle (ProgressBarIndicator), then I can change the ForegroundColor of my TextBlock, but I want to keep the standardlook of the Progressbar!

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Best Regards
Dougy

Answer (score 0):

As you are stating, if you set booth properties to the same **TemplateBinding** your text will be invisible. You have to create another property so you can manage them independently.

Create in your code a dependency property of type **Brush** and then template binding your TextBlock to that property.